# How can I use trained deepspeech AIs when they are provided trained on a Google Drive?

Tags: python, github, mozilla-deepspeech

I want to use the deepspeech model provided here https://github.com/AASHISHAG/deepspeech-german#results. They give trained models to Download and I want to use on of them ( https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L7ILB-TMmzL8IDYi_GW8YixAoYWjDMn1 ) but I have absolutely no clue how to come from these files to using it. I use python with VSCode. Sorry if this is a dumb question. Would really appreciate the help <3

Answer (score 0):

This seemed pretty clear:

https://github.com/AASHISHAG/deepspeech-german/blob/master/train_model.sh#L8-L18

> ```
> SCORER=${3:-german-text-corpus/kenlm.scorer}
> ```

Some links are offered to the extensive
kenlm documentation.
It's not a polished release,
but it does look like the author intends
for it to be runnable.

Comment: So I need to Download the Drive Folder and place it somewhere, then I open a new python script there and copy the code in there. Before I run the script I then have to check that I have installed all the python requirements from [link](https://github.com/AASHISHAG/deepspeech-german/blob/master/python_requirements.txt) and then it should work, am I right? I use Python3.0 with VSCode on Linux.